# Protection circuit with polyfuse and zener

Tags: protection, zener, over-voltage-protection, polyfuse

I'm designing a protection circuit with polyfuse and zener for DC 5v input. I have try it fisically but the polyfuse never trigger because the zener burns before when I plug 6-12V to the input.

[image: Polyfuse and zener protection]

My circuit current is less than 200 mA and the peaks currents is approximately 600mA. I decided place a 5V6 zener and a polyfuse 6V 0.75A. I thought the polyfuse would trigger before burning the zener.

How you could adjust these values for correct operation? Placing a higher power diode, could it be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Zeners for such high current isnt good solution, they are good for low power signals in case of protecting purpose. Rather disconnect the Vcc power rail with transistor (mosfet)  if overvoltage apear.

Comment: Specifically what zener diode did you use.

Comment: I have used BZT52C5V6

Comment: You have to put a resistor with the Zener to limit its break current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polyfuses (and fuses in general) take quite some time to trip and precision Zener might not survive long enough.

Did you consider specified TVS (Transient Voltage Suppressor) or ESD (electrostatic discharge) Diodes instead of the "Zener" ? Those are also Zener diodes, but not so much optimized for low noise or precision. Instead they can handle very large surge currents.

The fuse rating should have a current closer to 200mA, so it will trip faster. Getting one specced for e.g. 300-400 mA is sufficient, depending on how long you need that peak current. It can be good to spec the fuse lower than your peak current to accelerate fault tripping. But this is not an option, if you need the peak current for several seconds or more. Consult the fuse datasheet for trip speed at various current levels. The voltage rating of the fuse should be much higher than 6 V, compatible with the largest voltage that you want to protect against.

Littlefuse offers this plot in their PPTC datasheet of the part you chose:

[image]

So you see, that even picking something like the 0.35A / 30V part might be to *slow* to trip. You can try a few different parts though, to see what works.

As for the Diode, something beefy in e.g. a DO214 package has enough current capability. In the datasheet of STMicro for the [SMBJ5.0A/CA](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1761316.pdf) there is this plot:

[image]

The important parameter is the minimum breakdown voltage, which needs to be high than your intended supply voltage. A "5 Volt" TVS usually has about 6-6.5V minimum breakdown so would be suitable.

For much higher current, there is the option for a [resettable crowbar circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377258/12v-12a-resettable-crowbar-circuit) if you have trouble finding a beefy enough diode. Such circuits are used for higher power settings usually and not needed here, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm searching components to buy. I see this TVS (PESD5V0S1BA,115) and this PPTC (1206L035/16YR). Do you think it could work with my specifications? I want protect it if someone introduces a higher power supply or the poor quality power supply can produce a peak.

Comment: The fuse has to be rated in accordance with the duration you need maximum current which you didn't mention. Fuses have a plot of trip time vs current in their datasheets. Check this and include some headroom (e.g. factor 2). The Diode goes in the right direction, but better to check for a unidirectional type for your application and something a little bigger. The diodes, too, have power handling vs surge time plots that you must consider. If a single diode doesnt suffice, take a low power Zener + crowbar transistor.

Comment: I don't know whitch is the duration of the peak current, I get it from the datasheets of my components, but they don't say anything. They must be very low. I see one PPTC a little bigger (1206L050/15YR). About the diode, how big does it have to be? I don't understand several voltage parameters. I want to set my maximum voltage to 5.5V. Which can be choosen?

Comment: Some diode in a DO214 package, e.g. SMCJ1.5KE6.8A-TP will tolerate even 100W for roughly a second. That is bulky enough to trip slow PPTC. Ill edit my response.